# Allow user defined Strings in c#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, variables, parameterized

i'm asking about a pretty common feature I could not find any information about. I want to allow the user of my program to create custom strings with variables from the program.

Example:

I have a list:

```
ID   Name     Description       Value      Status
0    name 0   beschreibung 0    Wert 0     Status 0
1    name 1   beschreibung 1    Wert 1     Status 1
2    name 2   beschreibung 2    Wert 2     Status 2
3    name 3   beschreibung 3    Wert 3     Status 3
4    name 4   beschreibung 4    Wert 4     Status 4
5    name 5   beschreibung 5    Wert 5     Status 5
6    name 6   beschreibung 6    Wert 6     Status 6
7    name 7   beschreibung 7    Wert 7     Status 7
8    name 8   beschreibung 8    Wert 8     Status 8
9    name 9   beschreibung 9    Wert 9     Status 9
```

Now the user shall be able to define custom strings like:

*The Name of the Item with the Id {ID} is {Name}. It's Description is {Description}. It has the Value {Value} and the Status {Status}.*

I could write a custom parsing routine for those strings, but I hope to find a standard solution for that task. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you consider using String.Replace, String.Format or a Regex? Are the keys (Name, Description, Value and Status) fixed?

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is not _pretty common_, I'm afraid you have to write your own parsing routine. You have to lay down the rules, check the type conversions, etc. Isn't asking for data with a pre-defined GUI much easier?

Comment: String.Replace does the Trick.

@JohnWillemse: Okay, my statement that this is a commom feature may be a misconception. I work in the field of automation where you constantly build information strings with parameters that it is just common to me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may to allow the user use specified "variables" in string. For example:

```
var userstring = "The Name of the Item with the Id {ID} is {Name}. It's Description is {Description}. It has the Value {Value} and the Status {Status}.";
var result = userstring.Replace("{ID}", Id).Replace("{Name}", Name).Replace("{Description}", Description).Replace("{Value}", Value).Replace("{Status}", Status);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need. If you find the parameter, replace it. Works perfect for me.

Answer (score 3):

The standard solution for string formatting in C# (and in .NET in general) is to use [the String.Format method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). So your could for example do:

```
string reult = string.Format("The Name of the Item with the Id {0} is {1}. It's Description is {2}. It has the Value {3} and the Status {4}.",
       id, name, description, value, status);
```

Comment: This is okay if you're building the string during development. But I want to give the user the possibility to design his own strings. The position and count of the parameters may vary.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to replace placeholders such as `{ID}` and `{Name}` with the values from your list of objects. You could use a regex with a patterns such as

```
\{(?<key>[A-Za-z]+)\}
```

Which will find all instances of `{something}` and allow you to extract the `something` in order to get a value from your list.

Using the overload of [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) which takes an input string and a `MatchEvaluator` delegate, would allow you  to get the right value:

```
var myObject = new Dictionary<string,string>(){
    {"ID","1"},  
    {"Name","Bob Jones"},
    {"Description","A very nice man"},
    {"Value","1000"},
    {"Status","New"},
};
var regex = new Regex(@"\{(?<key>[A-Za-z]+)\}");
var input = "The Name of the Item with the Id {ID} is {Name}. It's Description is {Description}. It has the Value {Value} and the Status {Status}.";
string result = regex.Replace(input, m => myObject[m.Groups["key"].Value]);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/FLGTQW95860

The dictionary in that example is just to demonstrate the usage of the regex - there is no reason that couldnt be a `DataRow` or a custom object, or any other container for the properties.

Of course this solution does not contain any error handling (such as a placeholder where the property does not exist), which I suspect you will want to include if you're allowing the user to specify the string(s).

Answer (score 1):

Do you just mean:

```
var x = String.Format("The Name of the Item with the Id {0} is {1}. It's Description is {2}. It has the Value {3} and the Status {4}.",object.Id, object.Name, object.Description, object.Value, object.Status);
```

Or did I miss the point?

Answer (score 0):

You could define you own class and override the ToString:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var aString = new MyString() {Description = "desc", Id = 1, Name = "Ja", Status = "st", Value = "Val"};

        var myStrings = new List<MyString>() {aString};


        foreach (MyString myString in myStrings)
        {
            //The Name of the Item with the Id 1 is Ja. It's Description is desc. It has the Value val and the Status st.
            var outputStringVal = myString.ToString();
            //
        }
    }
}

public class MyString 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("The Name of the Item with the Id {0} is {1}. It's Description is {2}. It has the Value {3} and the Status {4}.", this.Id, Name, Description, Value, Status);
    }
}
```